# footer margin causing problems

Tags: html, css, layout, margin

I have an issue that is apparent depending on screen size.

My footer has a margin-top of 50px to allow for desired layout. The problem is that this seems to have the effect of placing the footer outside of not only it's containing div but of the html element, leaving a white gap at the bottom of the screen. I cannot figure out a way around this - any advice appreciated. Here is the url: http://preview.tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

If you cannot see the problem initially play around with the browser zoom function (ctrl + & - on my mac)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot and mention where exactly you are facing problem, and please mention on which screen resolution are targeting/watching?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be related to elements inside you "containing" div that are floated. Once you float an element inside an element that is not floated, you can run into the floated elements extending outside containing elements.

See this for more information.
http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/

Adding float: left to the class='holder' div would round up the child elements to appear contained in that element. (of course this might cause your layout to look different)

As for the white space at the bottom of the page. This seems to have something to do with the facebook and google icons.